# How to specify a more specific styling with .css.scss?

Tags: css, sass

I have the following CSS in my .css.scss file

```
.form-row {
  margin: 10px 10px 5px 10px;
  input[type='text'] {
    .single-line {
      height: 25px;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 0 5px;
    }
    height: 125px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 5px;
  }
}
```

So I want the height to be 125px unless class is "single-line"

I have the following html:

```
<div class='form-row'>
  <label for="user-name">Name</label>
  <input class="single-line" placeholder="Enter name here" type="text" />
</div>
```

However, the input text field is displayed with 125px height, not 25px which is what I want.

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to have omitted the ampersand (&) before the class.

**SCSS**

```
.form-row {
  margin: 10px 10px 5px 10px;
  input[type='text'] {
    &.single-line {
      height: 25px;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 0 5px;
    }
    height: 125px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 5px;
  }
}
```

**Output CSS**

```
.form-row {
  margin: 10px 10px 5px 10px;
}
.form-row input[type='text'] {
  height: 125px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
.form-row input[type='text'].single-line {
  height: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
```

[**SASSMeister Gist**](http://sassmeister.com/gist/7bc46b527be7ea164e8d)

Comment: Thank you.  That works.  Is the & syntax the same for SCSS, LESS and SASS?